# MongoDB, MongoEngine: How to get Document by its EmbeddedDocument?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

How can I get access to Document object when I have it's EmbeddedDocument object?
For example:

```
class ToySale(EmbeddedDocument):
    end_time = FloatField()
    percentage = IntField()

    @property
    def super_price(self):
        # I want to get access to Toy Document, something like that
        return self.toy.price - (self.percentage * self.toy.price / 100)

class Toy(Document)
    sale = EmbeddedDocumentField(ToySale)
    price = IntField()
```

Django ORM has analogous 'related_name' mechanism, but in mongoengine ORM I have not found anything like this.

Comment: Did not get your question. What are you trying to do. Get `Toy` by `ToySale`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

```
class ToySale(EmbeddedDocument):
    end_time = FloatField()
    percentage = IntField()
    uid = IntField()

    @property
    def super_price(self):
        toy = Toy.objects(sale__uid=self.uid)  # get Document by EmbeddedDocument
        return toy.price - (self.percentage * toy.price / 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get document by `EmbeddedDocument` fields.

For example by `end_time`:

```
Toy.objects(sale__end_time=3.14)
```

By `percentage`:

```
Toy.objects(sale__percentage=3)
```

By both:

```
Toy.objects(sale__end_time=3.14, sale__percentage=3)
```

If you already have `EmbeddedDocument` for example `toy_sale` you can do something like this:

```
Toy.objects(**{'sale__' + key: value 
               for key, value in toy_sale.to_mongo().items()
               if not key.startswith('_')})
```

or just:

```
Toy.objects(sale=toy_sale)
```

See documentation: http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#filtering-queries.

Comment: You've given me an idea.